# How to tell cakephp to go to someurl.com/action/var1/var2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Please bear with me as I am a cakephp noob.  I have this app that should go to www.name.com/complexes/somecomplex/unitnumber.  I can correctly get it to advance to www.name.com/complexes/somecomplex, but I don't know how to get the full path to my unit number.

Here is my controller:

```
class ComplexesController extends AppController {
    public $name='Complexes';
    public $uses=array('User', 'Complex', 'Unit');
    public $layout='pagelayout';



    public function view() { 
    $this->set('complex', strtoupper($this->params['id']));
    $c=$this->Complex->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('complex_name'=>$this->params['id'])));
    $this->set('complex_data', $c);
}
```

}

and here is my route

```
Router::connect('/complexes/:id', array('controller' => 'complexes', 'action' => 'view'));
```

Where do I write the action for calling up a specific unit?  Inside my 'view' action or another action called 'unit'?  And how do i tell cake to route to that?

Comment: I should add that I did create a function in my controller called units `public function unit() {
  
  $this->set('unitnum', strtoupper($this->params['id']));
  $u=$this->Unit->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('unitnum'=>strtoupper($this->params['id']))));
  $this->set('unitdesc', $u);`  but don't know how to access it correctly.  I do have all my model associations working correctly as I can access all my info in other controllers using the same associations.

Comment: I figured it out!  I had to pass an argument, called $unit in my view() function, where I set the conditions to look for the unitnumber that I had entered in the url ($unit).  Will post code when stackoverflow allows me to post the answer (in about 5 hours....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  I had to pass an argument, called $unit in my view() function, where I set the conditions to look for the unitnumber that I had entered in the url ($unit).  so, my code ended up looking like this:

```
public function view($unit=null) { 
    $this->set('complex', strtoupper($this->params['id']));
    $c=$this->Complex->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('complex_name'=>$this->params['id'])));
    $this->set('complex_data', $c);
    $u=$this->Unit->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('unitnum'=>$unit)));
    $this->set('unit', $u);
}
```

and in my routes file I added this line:

```
Router::connect('/complexes/:id/*', array('controller' => 'complexes', 'action' => 'view'));
```

And it worked!